# Symofny 3 - parent::__construct() cant be injected

Tags: php, service, symfony-3.4

I am trying to inject one service into another to call function from it but it throws an error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Base\Service\Shop\ShopService::__construct() must be an instance of App\Base\Service\AccountService, instance of ContainerSgqv3vy\appDevDebugProjectContainer given

And I think I implement everything correctly:

```
use App\Base\Service\AccountService;
use App\Base\Service\BaseService;


class ShopService extends BaseService
{
/**
 * @param AccountService $accountService
 */
public function __construct(AccountService $accountService)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->accountService = $accountService;
}
```

And calling in my function from it:

```
this->accountService->getMyFunction();
```

And my instantiated  class :

```
    class BaseService
{
    /** @var ContainerInterface  */
    var $container;
    var $em;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

service.yml

```
app.shop:
  class: App\Base\Service\ShopService
  arguments: ["@service_container", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
  public: true
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate that class?

Comment: You simply seem to be injecting the wrong dependency when instantiating the class. The issue is where it get's instantiated, not with the posted code.

Comment: I am instantiating existing service class AccountService. I don't know where the problem is. Can you show me in an example? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I am instantiating existing service class AccountService. I don't know where the problem is. Can you show me in an example? @AndreiLupuleasa

Comment: Please show us _all_ the relevant code. Right now, we don't even know what class you've posted. We can see the constructor and that it expects an instance of AccountService in the constructor, but that's it. We need to see where you instantiate the posted class (since that's where your issue is).

Comment: Sorry, ShopService is actually MainService as I edited my code. I updated that now. Thanks @MagnusEriksson

Comment: No worries. But you still haven't posted where you're instantiating that class.

Comment: I am not so good with english so I don't lnow what it stands for. I posted logic I am operating with. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Instantiate, create a new instance of the class. It should either be a `new ShopService(....)` or defined in some service provider or similar (I haven't worked with Symfony's framework so I'm not sure where you're registering classes to the container).

Comment: Maybe you think of service.yml. I added the code above. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: `arguments: ["@service_container", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]` - The first argument should probably be `AccountService`, not the container. Also, you don't seem to need the second argument (looking at the class constructor, it only expects one argument).

Comment: These two are arguments of extended BaseService class I entered above. it has $container and $em varibale. So,  parent::__construct() is missing those. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extend a class that has constructor arguments, you should keep those arguments and add any extra argument after.

Example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public function __construct(Foo $foo, Bar $bar) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

To instantiate this class, you would need to pass the container and the entity managaer:

```
$base = new BaseClass($fooInstance, $barInstance);
```

If you want to extend this class, it will most likely still need those dependencies + our new dependency:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    public function __construct(Foo $foo, Bar $bar, Duck $duck)
    {
        // The parent (BaseClass) requires Foo and Bar, 
        // or it will throw an error
        parent::__construct($foo, $bar);

        $this->duck = $duck;
    }
}
```

To instantiate our new ChildClass, we would need to pass three arguments:

```
$child = new ChildClass($fooInstance, $barInstance, $duckInstance);
```

Then, when you define our ChildClass in the service.yml, you need to have define all three dependencies:

```
app.childclass:
    class: ChildClass
    arguments: ["Foo", "Bar", "Duck"]
    ...
```

Since I'm not using Symfony myself, you must excuse for not knowing the exact syntax of service.yml, but the concept is the same.

Comment: You gave me an idea. I just added it in arguments. You saved me. Thanks. @MagnusEriksson